# How do I write a recursive function in Javascript to add up all of the string values of a deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Say I have this object:

```
{
    "prop1":"Hello",
    "prop2":{
         "prop1":{
              "prop1":"Tablecloth",
              "prop2":"Indians"
                },
          "prop2":"JuicyJuice"
           },
    "prop3":"Sponge",
    "prop4":{"Bob":"Squarepants"}
}
```

I would like a recursive function that will return `HelloTableclothIndiansJuicyJuiceSpongeSquarepants`.

Whatever object I put it, I want it to cycle though until it gets all of the strings and adds them all up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple implementation that should work for simple objects like this:

```
var walkProps = function(obj) {
    var s = "";
    for(var x in obj)
    {
        if(typeof obj[x] === "string")
            s += obj[x];
        else
            s += walkProps(obj[x]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWw53/)

Note, though, that that depends on the order in which `for-in` visits the properties on the object, which is **not specified** and can vary by engine and by how the object is constructed (for instance, the order in which the properties were added).

---

**Update:** With some slight modification, this can be used to return the values based on the *alphabetical* order of the keys. This method is not sensitive to implementation-dependent ordering of properties:

```
var walkProps = function(obj) {
    var s = "", i = 0, keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(), i;
    for(; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
        if(typeof obj[keys[i]] === "string")
            s += obj[keys[i]];
        else
            s += walkProps(obj[keys[i]]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

So even if `"prop3"` comes before `"prop2"` it will still return the same output.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWw53/2/)

Comment: Object properties have an order now, as of ECMAScript2015 (ES6), so that **if** the OP's object is defined as shown in the question, this will indeed reliably produce the desired output (on engines that correctly provide order).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good to know. Do you have a link or a section number I can reference?

Comment: Sorry, I'm surprised I didn't link it above. It's [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys). It's basically: Properties whose names that are strings that convert to integers first, in ascending numeric order; then properties whose names are strings that haven't already been listed, in the order the properties were added to the object; and then properties whose names are `Symbol`s (in addition order). That's own properties; prototype properties show up after own properties, following the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a function that loops over an object's properties and see if they are a string, and then append the strings to an output. If the property is an object rather than a string, you would want to call the function on this object and append it's return value to your total output.

You can loop over an object's properties using `for...in` like:

```
var MyObject = {
    'a': 'string1',
    'b': 'string2'
};

for (var key in MyObject) {
    var value = MyObject[key];
}
```

To check if a property is a string you would want to do:

```
typeof value === "string"
```

Which will return true/false accordingly.

Comment: No, `for-in` has no order, because objects have no order. See discussion on p.s.w.g's answer.

Comment: Ah, I did not see that he required a specific order, I'm not sure this is very doable then unless as you guys mentioned, alphabetical order would be fine.

Comment: Object properties have an order now, as of ECMAScript2015 (ES6).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `for( var b in a )` may not preserve ordering:

```
// Return array of string values
function getStrings(a) {
  if( typeof(a) == "string" ) return [a];
  var list = [];
  for( var b in a ) list = list.concat(getStrings(a[b]));
  return list;
}
```

Applied to OP's data:

```
var a = {
    "prop1":"Hello",
    "prop2":{
         "prop1":{
              "prop1":"Tablecloth",
              "prop2":"Indians"
                },
          "prop2":"JuicyJuice"
           },
    "prop3":"Sponge",
    "prop4":{"Bob":"Squarepants"}
}

getStrings(a).join(); // "Hello,Tablecloth,Indians,JuicyJuice,Sponge,Squarepants"

// Or as asked for by OP (again, order is not guaranteed)
getStrings(a).join(''); // "HelloTableclothIndiansJuicyJuiceSpongeSquarepants"
```

Comment: Except that it did preserve order in your example?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I'd consider it lucky rather than a guarantee in all cases. Perhaps some browsers conveniently preserve ordering.

Comment: @Matt sorry you're right, I was derp enough to ignore the first part of your answer. But I don't know who downvoted this answer as it is a viable solution. I'd upvote to offset that.

Comment: This answer relies on undocumented, unspecified behavior and the way the object was constructed to produce the output (as opposed to, say, `SquarepantsTableclothIndiansJuicyJuiceSpongeHello`), and essentially duplicates the first half of the previous answer by p.s.w.g.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did you read the disclaimer which was the first line of this answer? No such behavior is relied upon. In my interpretation of the OP's question, it's possible he could be giving an example rather than implying that the output MUST be ordered. If you disagree, then this is not a semantic argument I'm interested in having. If the OP finds this useful, great; if not, then let's all have a nice weekend anyway :)